# Getting String value from configuration file - LuCI

Tags: lua, openwrt

I am trying to build a web interface for an OpenWRT module for [Luci](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac). I have the following code:

```
m = Map("amld_cbi", translate ("amld_status"))
s = m:section(TypedSection, "amld_conf","Status")
fqdn = s:option(DummyValue, "fqdn", "FQDN value")
```

This works fine for displaying the value of fqdn (which is located inside amld_cbi) on the screen. Now I want the String value itself.

When I try to do:

```
m = Map("amld_cbi", translate ("amld_status"))
s = m:section(TypedSection, "amld_conf","Status")
fqdn = s:option(DummyValue, "fqdn", "FQDN value")

luci.sys.call("amld " .. fqdn)
```

I get the following error:

```
The called action terminated with an exception:
/usr/lib/lua/luci/model/cbi/amld/amld_status.lua:25: attempt to concatenate global 'fqdn' (a table value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    /usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:448: in function 'dispatch'
    /usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:195: in function </usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:194>
```

Does anybody know how to get the actual value from the variable fqdn?

Comment: The error says `fqdn` is a table. Maybe find out what fields and contents in this table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just figured it out, looks like you have to add the following:

```
m = Map("amld_cbi", translate ("amld_status"))
s = m:section(TypedSection, "amld_conf","Status")
fqdn = s:option(DummyValue, "fqdn", "FQDN value")

fqdn_string = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "fqdn")

luci.sys.call("amld " .. tostring(fqdn_string)) **the tostring function may not be necessary **
```

Where my amld_cbi file looks like this:

```
config amld_conf 'amld'
    option fqdn 'www.google.com'
```